# Odoo 10 web service api not updating object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to update an existing product's QoH (quantity on hand) in the Odoo 10 database with new values via the web service API to sync the data from our e-store. I'm doing it throw a rails app.

I've debugged and apparently the Odoo side is just not updating the record. Do you have some thoughts on what could it be?

```
@models.execute_kw(@db, @uid, @password, 'product.product', 'write', [[odoo_product_id], {
            qty_available: new_qoh
        }])
```

And when I read again the object:

```
@models.execute_kw(@db, @uid, @password, 'product.product', 'read', [odoo_product_id], {fields: %w(x_code qty_available)})
```

The `quantity_available` still the same old one.

Answer (score 0):

That's just because `qty_available` is a computed field [without inverse](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L27) method, which should be there if you want to write into the field. You will need to create `stock.quant`s for the product or just use the [mechanism to update the quantity on hand](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/stock/wizard/stock_change_product_qty.py) (a wizard, which can be used by web api, too).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!